# stack comparision in java

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

```
    for(int i=1;i<str_arry.length;i++){

        if(s.lastElement().equals(str_arry[i])){

            s.push(str_arry[i]);

        }
        else {
            if(!s.isEmpty()) s.pop();
        }



    }
```

---

i was not able to detect why this one is giving Exception in thread "main"

> java.util.NoSuchElementException  at
>   java.util.Vector.lastElement(Vector.java:503)

Since the code s.pop() is the cause of that exception but how could this be possible if it's i used s.isEmpty().

Comment: Because it's not `pop` that's causing it: it's `s.lastElement()`, as indicated by `java.util.Vector.lastElement` in the stack trace.

Comment: *Why* do you think it's `pop()` when the error message says "at `lastElement()`"? Also, the next line in the stack trace will show you the line number in *your* code, which would also be pointing to the `if(s.lastElement().equals(str_arry[i]))` line, not the `if(!s.isEmpty()) s.pop()` line. Learn to read the error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `s.pop()` that's causing the exception: it's `s.lastElement()`, as indicated by `java.util.Vector.lastElement` in the stack trace. This means that you have to check for `s.isEmpty()` before calling `s.lastElement()` too.

You can't execute any of the loop body if the stack is empty: move the check outside:

```
for (int i=1;i<str_arry.length;i++) {
  if (s.isEmpty()) break;  // Or some other way to handle it.

  if (s.lastElement().equals(...) {
    s.push(...);
  } else {
    s.pop();
  }
}
```